# Can't move files to trash

Tags: finder, trash

Lately, my computer will not let me move my files to the trash. It doesn't give me an error or anything, it'll just give me the usual 'moving file to trash' message and it gets stuck right there. I can't stop the process and the process of moving the file into the trash never finishes. I have to force reload finder to get rid of that message and even then, the file is not in the trash. I'm honestly not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: I'd run a repair from disk utility after booting & holding Cmd/r

Comment: do you have any message in the Console ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer or leaving it off fir a little bit because it may help to give your computer a break if it is at constant use

Comment: @DannyHutchinson - my Mac has been running 24/7 since 2008, restarting only for OS updates & the occasional dust & clean; no problems yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you reset your Finder by deleting its property file. As you can't delete it via Finder, you'll have to use Terminal for that

- Open Terminal
- type `cd ~/Library/Preferences` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- type `rm com.apple.finder.plist` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then restart your computer.